# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null when creating goggle events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to create events in Google Calendar from Google Sheets, and this script was working fine, but now I'm getting the following error;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null scheduleShifts @ Calendar Posting.gs:12

I think It has something to do with the calendar ID but I'm not sure. This is the code - where do you think I'm going wrong?

```
function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId");
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("G5:I7").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[6];
    var endTime = shift[7];
    var volunteer= shift[5];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm worried that your error message of `Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null` is due to that `eventCal` of `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId")` is `null`. So, how about confirming `calendarId` again?

Comment: @Tanaike seems to be ok, checked again then - it's just my email address, could it be a permission issue possibly?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `seems to be ok`, when you confirmed the value of `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId")`, the value was not `null`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry I thought you wanted me to check it again. Ok, stupid question how do I confirm the value?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `how do I confirm the value?`, how about using `Logger.log(CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId"))`?

Comment: @Tanaike thankyou - yep it's coming up as Null

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `it's coming up as Null`, I think that my 1st comment is the answer for your question. In this case, how about confirming `calendarId` and the actual Calendar of `calendarId` again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248787/discussion-between-roostermagic22-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike sorry I don't understand. This is obviously beyond me I will find another way.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have answered your additional question in the chart. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Try `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);`

Comment: @idfurw I got this error mate 11:45:01 AM Error 
ReferenceError: calendarID is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("G5:I7").getValues();
  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[2];
    var volunteer = shift[0];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

You could rewrite it like this:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ss.getRange("E1").getValue());
  var vs = ss.getRange("G5:I7").getValues();
  vs.forEach(([t,s,e]) => {
    eventCal.createEvent(t, s, e);
  });
}
```

Comment: I got this error mate 11:43:41 AM Error 
Exception: Invalid argument: title
scheduleShifts @ Test.gs:11

Comment: I think I might re-write the damn thing lol

Comment: You had incorrect indices